# Alert something if javascript not enabled without using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to make a window to popup if javascript disabled?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the noscript tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: To display a message if javascript is disabled. Is there a rule against linking to w3schools? Or just your personal preference?

Comment: Have a read  [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/). It is very telling. w3schools are horrific

Comment: Other than using the `target="_blank"` on an anchor tag to open the link in a new window, there's nothing that will do what you're asking without JavaScript (or equivalent)

Comment: Actually you can use CSS as mentioned. Here is a cool link http://pauljablonski.net/pure-css-popup-for-any-content.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #body {display:none;}
        #alertdiv {display:inline;}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

where `#alertdiv` is a div designed to show the message you want (hidden by default) and `#body` the id of your main div that will be hidden if javascript is not activated. But it is optional.

A popup is a `window.open` command and doesn't exist without javascript. You have to emulate something similar. [update 2015: bootstrap, jquery... now offer wonderful ways of displaying alerts without requiring popups, as easily as `$("#alert-box").modal("show");`]

The idea is to use CSS to show parts of your page only when javascript is disabled.

Side-note: this won't validate w3c.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
    <div id="NoScriptPopup">Javascript is disabled on your browser</div>    
    <div id="YourContent">/*Your page content goes here*/</div>
    <style>
        #YourContent
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("NoScriptPopup").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("YourContent").style.display = 'block';
    </script>
</body>
```

So if javascript is disabled on a browser, the #NoScriptPopup will appear and your content will be hidden. You could style #NoScriptPopup div using css to make it look like a popup.